# Blender script keyframe in loop doesn't affect first element

Tags: python, keyframes

Here is mine area with objects (frame 0):
[image]

I'm trying to make objects move with python script. Every object on list should move into center of my area. I'm using for loop. Unfortunately first element doesn't want to keep it's initial position on 0 frame. It looks like it is replacing 0 frame position with 20 frame position and then it works properly but it makes every move 20 frames before rest of them. I don't have idea why it is not working properly. Can you see my code and try to find out what is wrong with it?

Code below:

```py
new_loc = [0,0,0]

frame_num = 0

for obj in creatures_names:

    ob = bpy.data.objects[obj.name]
    scene.frame_set(frame_num)
    ob.keyframe_insert(data_path='location', index = -1)

new_radius = radius - 4

while frame_num < settings['frames']:
    frame_num += 20
    for obj in creatures_names:

        ob = bpy.data.objects[obj.name]

        loc = obj.location
        x = float(loc[0])
        y = float(loc[1])
        z = float(loc[2])
        creature_angle = math.atan(y/x)
        print(creature_angle)
        new_x = new_radius * math.cos(creature_angle)
        new_y = new_radius * math.sin(creature_angle)
        new_loc[2] = z
        new_loc[0] = new_x
        new_loc[1] = new_y

        ob.location = new_loc
        ob.keyframe_insert(data_path='location', index = -1)
        frame_num = 20
        scene.frame_set(frame_num)

    new_radius -= 4
```

Here is frame 20:
[image]

And frame 40:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have more than one problem:
One try using `obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='location', frame=frame_num)`

instead of

`scene.frame_set(frame_num)
    ob.keyframe_insert(data_path='location', index = -1)`.

Also, you set `frame_num = 20` inside your while loop... which should cause an infinite loop.

[How to keyframe_insert without moving the object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155960/how-to-keyframe-insert-without-moving-the-object)

Comment: `frame_num = 20` should be in comment. I lost '#' while copying. But your solution works perfect for me. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

**Use `Vector` math.**

Can completely avoid any trig methods and use vector math instead.   The length of an objects `location` vector is its radius from the origin of its parent. In the case of no parent, the distance from (0, 0, 0)

To move it to half the distance from the origin can simply `ob.location *= 0.5` no angles necessary. To do this for only x, y `ob.location.xy * = 0.5`.

To test made a list of all cube objects in the scene (well those with names starting with "Cube") The radius is reduced by 1 each 20 frames from 0 to 60

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

cubes = [o for o in scene.objects if o.name.startswith("Cube")]

start, stop, step = 0, 61, 20 # kfs at 0, 20, 40, 60

for f in range(start, stop, step):
    for o in cubes:
        o.keyframe_insert("location", frame=f)
        radius = o.location.length
        if radius < 1e-7: #  at center
            continue
        o.location.xy *= (radius - 1) / radius
```

If attached to using trig, suggest using `atan2(y, x)`

```
import bpy
from math import atan2, degrees
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

cubes = [(o, atan2(*o.location.yx)) for o in scene.objects if o.name.startswith("Cube")]

for o, angle in cubes:
    print(o, degrees(angle))
```

One last thing it would appear `creatures_names` in question script is a list of objects not names, making for unnecessarily using `obj`, and `ob` which are the same

```
creature_names = ("Pig", "Goat", "Sheep")
creatures = [(name, scene.objects.get(name)) for name in creature_names]
for name, ob in creatures:
    if ob is None:
        print(f"Creature {name} is missing")
        continue
```

Comment: What I want to reach finally is to make creatures move randomly (random direction) but getting closer and closer to the center. I don't know how to make it move like this yet but i think vectors should be useful for me as well. Thanks!