# How to programatically rotate a rigid body?

Tags: modeling, python, scripting

I have a rigid body being affected by gravity. I want it to rotate as it accelerates. When choosing the animated option for Rigid Body, my object stops being affected by gravity. What I've tried goes along the lines of:

```
for i in range(250):
     bpy.context.obj.rigid_body.kinematic = True
     onj.rotation_euler[1] = currentAngleList[i] #currentAngleList is a list of angles my object rotates at
     bpy.context.obj.rigid_body.kinematic = False
```

Which has no result on rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, don't keep setting "kinematic = False".  That will prevent animation on the object.  Set it to True once.

Then, you'd also want to set rotation KeyFrames to the angle list, so that it attains the currentAngleList[i] at frame[i].  So it is animated just like any other object, as described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155960/how-to-keyframe-insert-without-moving-the-object).

Here is a scripting fragment, sans your array and loop:

```
import bpy

rb_obj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
rb_obj.rigid_body.kinematic = True
rb_obj.animation_data_create()
# replace the next statement with yer 'for' loop:
i=1
rb_obj.rotation_euler[1] = 11.0
rb_obj.keyframe_insert( data_path="rotation_euler", frame=i )
```